# foreach loop returning only one value when working with <iframe>

Tags: php, iframe, foreach

Following is the PHP code I'm facing problem with:

```
<?php 
    $query="SELECT `url` FROM `videos";
    $query_run=mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run)){
        $result[]=$row;}
        foreach($result as $var){
            $url=$var['0'];
            echo "<iframe width='250' height='200' src='".$url."' frameborder='0'>";
        }
?>
```

The problem is that it **returns only one result** of `<iframe>` tag, **but**  *echoing out  `$url`* ***i.e***

```
<?php 
    $query="SELECT `url` FROM `videos`";
    $query_run=mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run)){
        $result[]=$row;}
        foreach($result as $var){
            $url=$var['0'];
            echo $url;
        }
?>
```

returns all the available results.

Please help

Comment: close the `</iframe>` tag. use `echo "<iframe width='250' height='200' src='".$url."' frameborder='0'></iframe>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify a  closing tag `</iframe>`.

```
<?php 
    $query="SELECT `url` FROM `videos";
    $query_run=mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run)){
        $result[]=$row;}
        foreach($result as $var){
            $url=$var['0'];
            echo "<iframe width='250' height='200' src='".$url."' frameborder='0'></iframe>";
        }
?>
```